# The directory - files that could conflict

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new ro reactjs and so i am trying to learn my way through it. I have ran into a problem trying to create a new react project.. i have updated node and npm to the latest version but i keep getting the same error or rather message. Can anyone please help?
the following is the message i keep getting.

```
stelg@----MacBook ~ % npx create-react-app monsters-rolodex
The directory monsters-rolodex contains files that could conflict:

  node_modules/
  package-lock.json
  package.json
  public/
  src/

Either try using a new directory name, or remove the files listed above.
```

new to reactjs at the moment

Comment: You may need to share the structure of monsters-rolodex. It looks as though you're trying to create it in a place where create-react-app has already been run and the names are the same? https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started

Comment: There's already a node.js project there. You probably need to make a new folder for your project.